# Form_tag parameters in nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that doesn't have a model associated with it, so I'm using `form_tag` rather than `form_for`.  As expected, when the user submits the form each of the fields is included in the params hash. But the form will change a lot and I would prefer to have a hash within the params hash that will hold all of the form field values so that I don't have to change my controller every time I change my form.

Is there a way to put the form field values into a nested hash like form_for does?  I'd like to be able to take all of the form fields and convert them to json by doing something like `params[:form_fields].to_json`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) inside a `form_tag` for a more formal way of expressing a namespace.

```
fields_for :form_fields do |ff|
  ff.text_field :my_text_field
  ff.select :my_select_tag
end
```

Alternatively just namespace all your form inputs, as such:

```
text_field_tag "form_fields[my_text_field]"
select_tag "form_fields[my_select_tag]" ...
```

etc. Then you will get `params[:form_fields] = {:my_text_field => "foo", :my_select_tag => "bar"}`, which I think is what you wanted.

Comment: That seems to be doing exactly what I need.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm finding strong params doesn't match the symbol :my_text_field to the string this generated of ":my_text_field"

Comment: the string names of input elements are mapped to symbols, so `"my_text_field"` will match `:my_text_field`, `":my_text_field"` will probably not.

Comment: is this still possible with rails 4.1 ? I am doing just that, and my html has grouping like above with form_fields. it works for fields with a related active record object. but not with custom fields. I receive their key/value in the params top level.