# trouble passing through params with form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm having trouble with my form tag in my app.

I have a form_tag on my user/show page. The following code does not deliver any errors, however it is not writing to the database. From what I can tell I need to add @position_game_stat somewhere to my form_tag, because my form is taking the data as nil.

user/show.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "position_game_stats", :action => "create"}, :method => "post") do %>
```

`<%= label_tag :at_bats %><br />`
`<%= number_field_tag :at_bats %>`
`<%= submit_tag("submit") %>`
`<% end %>`

position_game_stats controller under create

> @position_game_stat = PositionGameStat.new(params[:position_game_stat])

Here is the server log

> Started POST "/position_game_stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-20 17:55:47 -0500
>   Processing by PositionGameStatsController#create as HTML
>     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"C2FJNDfVPILGx05DI2XqRO5wjC79Of7W4SoLvVpnh+4=", "user_id"=>"{:value=>1}", "date"=>{"year"=>"2013", "month"=>"6", "day"=>"20"}, "at_bats"=>"666", "hits"=>"6", "runs"=>"6", "doubles"=>"6", "triples"=>"6", "homeruns"=>"6", "steals"=>"6", "walks"=>"6", "strike_outs"=>"6", "commit"=>"submit"}
>      (0.1ms)  begin transaction
>     SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "position_game_stats" ("at_bats", "created_at", "date", "doubles", "hits", "homeruns", "runs", "steals", "strike_outs", "triples", "updated_at", "user_id", "walks") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["at_bats", nil], ["created_at", Thu, 20 Jun 2013 22:55:47 UTC +00:00], ["date", nil], ["doubles", nil], ["hits", nil], ["homeruns", nil], ["runs", nil], ["steals", nil], ["strike_outs", nil], ["triples", nil], ["updated_at", Thu, 20 Jun 2013 22:55:47 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", nil], ["walks", nil]]
>      (163.5ms)  commit transaction
>     User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1

Thanks in advanced...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use form_for tag.

View

```
<%= form_for @position_game_stat do |f| %>
  <%= f.number_field :at_bats %>
  <%= f.submit  %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
def new
  @position_game_stat = PositionGameStat.new
end
```

Comment: thank you. I was trying to avoid form_for since this form_tag approach allowed me to use my existing controller code, but since I can't seem to get the params to pass this in as @position_game_stat I think I will take your suggestion.

Comment: I think you are looking for this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115977/form-tag-parameters-in-nested-hash). You need to nest :at_bats like  `position_game_stat[:at_bats]`.